# Query regarding Pivot table in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot

I need some help with the Excel pivot table whose data is actually coming from SQL query.

Pivot data:
[image: Pivot data]

I don't want the highlighted part which is actually the sum of the values appearing below them.
These numbers are the number of leaves of a person and should not be (Summed)

Comment: Please check [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/show-or-hide-subtotals-and-totals-in-a-pivottable-fc4d8406-f230-4762-aa2f-310826f3e5e2). I've also voted to close the question due to the nature of this question.

Comment: thanks so much. that worked. sometimes things are so easy yet troubles us for days